# com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException Documentation

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm making an intellij plugin. I get this notice when i run some code in the `selectionChanged` method of the `FileEditorManagerListener`.

I have no idea what the documentation alludes to - all references to this bend towards some android bug, but I'm not working on android, this is an actual intellij plugin.

Any thoughts - I suspect I'm meant to not "run" this code while the app is indexing, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple - although, of course, the intellij team seem to want to make their plugin code *so hard* to understand. Why people don't bother with actual documentation is just beyond me. It's a crying shame.

Here:

```
@Override
public void fileOpened(@NotNull FileEditorManager source, @NotNull VirtualFile file) {
   try {
      showItem(toolWindow.getComponent(), file);
   } catch (IndexNotReadyException ex) {
      DumbService.getInstance(project).runWhenSmart(() -> showItem(toolWindow.getComponent(), file) );
   }
}
```

The trick is to wrap in a try/catch block, and then use the "DumbService". This isn't a complete solution, the doco *mysteriously* warns that using the DumbService might need some checks...

...but if *the people who wrote the documentation cannot be bothered to express what the checks are, and the people who wrote the code couldn't be bothered to write code that didn't need checks* then what do I care.

I mean, it's not like a nuclear bomb will go off, right?

Comment: Why are you complaining? This is an *internal* API. It was never the intent that this woud be a public API, nor documented. To some extent, we are lucky that we have access to the inner workings of intellij platform, enabling us to make plugins. "research" type activities like you just went through are par for the course. Sometimes you get answer from intellij developers, other times you must nut it out yourself... in any case, personally I found the exception self explanatory.